# Cannot use php-intl extension on CentOS with cPanel

Tags: php, centos6.5

I have CentOS release 6.5 (Final) with cPanel installed. And I need to use php-intl extension. Therefore, I installed it via pecl module installation through cPanel. I had also to install libicu via yum, otherwise pecl module compilation was failing. Now when I'm trying to use this extension in php, I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: transliterator_transliterate():
>   Could not create transliterator with ID "NFKD; Latin; Latin/US-ASCII;
>   [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; " (transliterator_create: unable to open ICU
>   transliterator with id "NFKD; Latin; Latin/US-ASCII;
>   [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; ": U_INVALID_ID)

How can I fix this problem?

P.S. I don't get such an error on Windows or on another CentOS, where I don't have cPanel.

UPD:

I solved this issue myself. It seems the original ICU library just didn't contain the needed transliterators. I added REMI repository (http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror) and installed libicu-last and libicu-last-devel from this repo (via yum). Then I recompiled the extension using `pecl install -f intl-3.0.0`.

Comment: This question is 2 years old, and some "special" guy decided to downvote the question and the answer without any comment on that. Nice... Good practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue myself. It seems the original ICU library just didn't contain the needed transliterators. I added REMI repository (http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror) and installed libicu-last and libicu-last-devel from this repo (via yum). Then I recompiled the extension using `pecl install -f intl-3.0.0`.